# How to output a list of social icons in custom function?

Tags: php

I have an unordered list of social icons I would like to output, but am stumped on how I would I do it with my current function (use an array, $figure?) -

So my raw code is currently (which checks if a field is filled, and if so shows the icon on the front-end) -

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_twitter', true ) ) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_twitter', true ) ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View Twitter Profile', 'booka' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<?php } if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_facebook', true ) ) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_facebook', true ) ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View FaceBook Profile', 'booka' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<?php } if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_googleplus', true ) ) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'member_googleplus', true ) ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View Google Plus Profile', 'booka' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I would like to insert these list items into the following (and looping through them) -

```
if ($layout_style == "style-one") {

                $html .= "<div class='team-member'>";
                $html .= "<h3 class='member-name'>$title</h3>";
                $html .= "<div class='member-role'>$member_role</div>";
                $html .= "<ul class='social-icons'>";

                $html .= "</ul>";

                $html .= "</div>";

            }
```

Have tried a few unsuccessful ways already.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know what you are asking for.  Let me know if I missed the mark:

```
$socials = array(
    array('twitter', 'Twitter', 'twitter'),
    array('facebook', 'FaceBook', 'facebook'),
    array('googleplus', 'Google Plus', 'google-plus'),
);

if ($layout_style == "style-one") {
    $html .= "<div class='team-member'>";
    $html .= "<h3 class='member-name'>$title</h3>";
    $html .= "<div class='member-role'>$member_role</div>";
    $html .= "<ul class='social-icons'>";

    foreach ($socials as $social) {
        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member_' . $social[0], true)) {
            $html .= "<li><a href=\"" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member_' . $social[0], true) . "\" title=\"" . _e('View " . $social[1] . " Profile', 'booka') . "\"><i class=\"fa fa-" . $social[2] . "\"></i></a></li>";
        }
    }

    $html .= "</ul>";
    $html .= "</div>";
}
```